# How to deal with new line characters in Windows vs Unix in Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

Currently I am doing below task.

1. Create a small file in Windows using Python
2. Transfer this file to remote Unix environment using Paramiko Python library SFTP module

Problem faced:

Newline created on Windows is not properly converted to Unix new line character during the transfer. I see `^M` characters inside the file on my remote host.

Any idea or suggestion how can I get rid of this behaviour.

When I do the transfer of the same file using WinSCP, I do not face this problem. I guess WinSCP has a built-in capability to handle this.

Python version used 3.5.

Step 1:

```
with open(myNewFile.txt,'w') as fileToUpload:
    fileToUpload.write('MyOwnTxt'+'\n')
```

Step 2:

```
COMP = remoteServerHost
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(COMP, username=user, password=password, allow_agent = False)
src = myNewFile.txt
dst = "/remotePath/myNewFile.txt"
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
ftp.put(src , dst)
ftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

I am little surprised because no one has specified this problem in SO or any other forum. So it makes me feel is there something wrong on my Windows machine :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paramiko does not support converting EOL sequences of transferred files.

You have to convert the contents before uploading it.

See [Define transfer mode when trying to SFTP files using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58099119/850848).

Comment: Thank you @Martin, I accept this answer for my question. I learnt that Winscp is able to do the conversion because it has the option of Text transfer where as paramiko just has binary transfer.